# How do I make an API call for each result from a sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, api, cron, sequelize.js

I have a cron job which will query my database and find any items that have a status of 'SUBMITTED' or 'PROCESSING' for each of which I want to make an API call to an external API and then update the database with the response

```
  const results = await myTable.findAll({
    where: {
      status: {
        [op.or]: [
          'SUBMITTED',
          'PROCESSING'
        ],
      },
    },
  })
```

I tried using a forEach but that gave the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined"

```
  await Promise.all(
        results.forEach(async item => {
          makeAPICall(item.id).then(response => updateDBItemStatus(item.id, response)
        }),
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting all the responses from the external api using Promise.all and then updating the db. Wrap the whole thing in a async block.

```
let api_call_array = results.map( item => makeAPICall(item.id));
const api_response = await Promise.all([api_call_array])

let update_db_item = api_response.map((response, index)=> {
  return updateDBItemStatus(results[index].item.id, response)
})
const update_response = await Promise.all([update_db_item])
```

Comment: Thanks, results.map works, but it can be much simpler than your solution.

      results.map(item =>
        makeAPICall(item.claimId)
          .then(response =>
            updateDBItemStatus(item.id, response),
          )
      )

Comment: Yes Micheal, it will be simpler,  to make it more efficient, we can use it, since it will not block for every id, you can just find the more efficient one and use it.